# matplotlib multiple connections to an event handler?

Tags: python, events, event-handling, matplotlib

```
import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print matplotlib.__version__, matplotlib.get_backend()

def hit(event):
  sys.stderr.write('hit\n')

fig = plt.figure()
cid0 = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', hit)
cid1 = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', hit)
print cid0, cid1
plt.show()
```

With the code above, why can't I have both mouse press event and key press events firing hit?  It seems in the order above only the key press events work, whereas if I swap the lines 10 and 11 around (order cid0 and cid1 assignment), then only the mouse events work.  I.e. whichever one I connected first hogs the event handler.  Is this a built in limitation of matplotlib, or am I trying to connect multiple events in the wrong way?

**edit with some extra info**: My `matplotlib.__version__` is `1.1.0`.  I have tried with `GTKAgg` and `TkAgg` backends with the same result.  Using python and ipython, with or without `-wthread -pylab`, `ipython qtconsole --pylab=inline`, does not make a difference.  The connection ids I get are `cid0 == cid1 == 6`.

***edit 2***: My problem still remains today with matplotlib version `1.2.x` and `TkAgg` backend, `sys.version 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) [GCC 4.6.1]`

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.  I have tried it with  "ipython -pylab" followed by "run yourcode" and "python yourcode.py"  -- cheers.  I think I am using the GTK backend, but I am not sure.  Under what conditions are you running?

Comment: interesting.  could you please tell me your `sys.version`, `matplotlib.backends.backend` and your `matplotlib.__version__`?

Comment: mine are `'2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) \n[GCC 4.5.2]'`,  `'GTKAgg'`, and `'1.1.0'`, respectively, by the way.

Comment: Also works fine for me (both print `hit`) with `2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) [GCC 4.4.3]`, Matplotlib version `0.99.1.1` and `TkAgg` as default backend.

Comment: I was wrong, it sure isn't the GTK backend.    sys.version => "
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) \n
[GCC 4.4.5]"    
matplotlib.backends.backend  => TkAgg

 matplotlib.__version__  => '0.99.3'

Comment: thank you for the comments.  unfortunately putting `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` at the top of the script does not resolve my issue.. perhaps it's a new bug ?

Comment: i noticed that `cid0 == cid1`, which smells funny.  if i use `hit_ = lambda x: hit(x)` and then connect one of them to `hit_` instead, i get `cid0 != cid1` and the event handler is fired for both use-cases as expected.  this is the current workaround i will use, but if anyone can get to the root cause of this i would be interested to hear, thanks !

Comment: both callbacks work for me with :`sys.version 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) [GCC 4.5.2]`
`matplotlib.backends.backend GTKAgg`
`matplotlib.__version__ 0.99.3`

Comment: is there anyone with same versions as mine can confirm the problem?  by the way, i found the more usual way to print the backend is, duh, `matplotlib.get_backend()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you stumbled upon this bug: [Multiple mpl_connect calls ignored](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/585)

Comment: Thanks.  I upgraded to `1.3.x` recently, and the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and both the actions (mouse and keyboard) did the trick : i had "hit" every time.

I use ubuntu 10.10, python 2.6.6 and matplotlib 0.99.3, all installed by synaptic (not by downloading latest version and running setup.py, as this has lead me into several big problems previously).

I also have python2.6-dev installed, as this adds the missing ".h" headers in most cases.

Hope this helps.​

Comment: yes, i have had it working in the past before with the synaptic versions.

Comment: Which backend are you using ?  I mostly have explicit backend imports, such as : from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg   as Canvas
 but when not specified, you use the default from a file : 
/home/project29/.matplotlib/.matplotlibrc

backend      : GTKAgg

Comment: (too late to complete previous edit)  -  Also have a look at http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/customizing.html

Comment: it's stated in the comments under the question, i have GTKAgg backend.  but i have tried with other, i have also the problem with TkAgg backend.

Comment: I have cid=6 for key and cid=7 for mouse - 0.99.3 TkAgg
6 7
hit
hit

Comment: "yes, i have had it working in the past before with the synaptic versions" :: maybe you'd better glue to those versions ...

Comment: i need some of the features that are added in v1.0